# After adding the file in hive(hadoop),it is not visible in warehouse?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I can add a file in hive like:

```
hive> add file /home/vis/Documents/def.txt;

hive>list files;
/home/vis/Documents/def.txt
```

Now the question is, the above file is not visible in my warehouse.

Is it possible to see it in the hive warehouse (`/user/hive/warehouse`).

If not, then how can I see that file in hive?

Answer (score 1):

The [Hive *add* command puts the file in distributed cache](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveResources). This is *mapred.local.dir*. Distributed cache is intended to distribute files that need to be present on all nodes for use by a MR job, in this case for your Hive query.

Cloudera has [a document that gives examples](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hive/language_manual/data-manipulation-statements.html).
Depending on your objective, you may want to load the data into hdfs first, then [create an external table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT,
     page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING,
     ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User',
     country STRING COMMENT 'country of origination')
 COMMENT 'This is the staging page view table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';
```

If your intent was for the data file to be part of the warehouse, you can omit the *external* keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT,
    page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING,
    ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User')
COMMENT 'This is the page view table'
PARTITIONED BY(dt STRING, country STRING)
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;
```